memcached error "Maximum connections must be greater than 0" in tempo-distributed
I am using  Tempo Distributed Helm Chart to version : 1.9.0
And enabled memcached, but I am getting below error in memcached logs and memcache pods are not getting up.
Maximum connections must be greater than 0
Maximum connections must be greater than 0
Maximum connections must be greater than 0
Maximum connections must be greater than 0

Can you please help here to eliminate this issue?

Had the same issue. In my case it was due to having something in the   spec.template.spec.containers.args field (by default this is empty in the StatefulSet manifest). Removing it has fixed the startup issue.

Yep, same for me. It got resolved. Thanks
